# Tailwind 304 Error would like an explanation why

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

When I type in the className it won’t change the style

I’ve tried htaccess and I’ve gotten a warning about the content not being implemented correctly but I am pretty sure it is.

This is the tailwind config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./poke/index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{css,js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}",
    "./poke/src/pages/**/*.html",
    "./poke/src/pages/**/*.jsx",
    "./poke/src/pages/**/*.css"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This is the warning

```
warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```